# Refusal of UK tourism visa due to wrong salary calculation

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

15 Nov 2017 Applications submission & biometrics taken (Myself & Spouse).
23 Nov 2017 Company receives a call to confirm employment.
24 Nov 2017 Decision made email sent.
27 Nov 2017 Received refusal & documents.

I was refused entry due to:

Refusal Letter says I claim income of RM 60000 per month.
However its RM 5000 Per month, calculating to RM 60000 per year.

Refusal Letter says they referred to 2 'two' statements from two different banks.
However I submitted 3 'three' statements from three different banks, whereby I use 1 for my life savings 'HSBC Bank' & 1 for my monthly expenses 'CIMB Bank' & 1 for salary deposits 'May bank', as I am assigned to operate the company online bank transactions. It appears ECO did not come across my MayBank statements as it clearly shows company transactions to my personal account.

At outset, I thought it could be a typing error, but when reading my wife's refusal, they again repeated the same reason.

Kindly advise what to do as visiting my favorite club stadium & attend a live match has been always my childhood dream. taking into account that I have come to your forum & learned a lot from those been refused & tried to make our applications as perfect as I could.

Should I contact VAC in Kuala Lumpur or address the Manila Visa Centre where the Processing took place? Should it be by phone or via email??

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's most likely that you've made a typo when making the application. Your best way forward is to simply fill in a new one, with correct salary information, assuming that there is no more to the refusal letter.

Comment: Wait, what, why did you include company account statements at all? What does it have to do with your application?

Comment: No, I didn't include company account statements. It's my personal  bank statements but I use it to receive my salary from company account. Anyway thanks for your comments

Comment: @HankyPanky, I double-checked, it's even RM 4850 per month after tax deductions. I'm really hesitant whether to submit a fresh application in the next few days explaining that error or postpone my trip a couple of months as this could increase my chances to get approved. please advise..

Comment: I do not think that this is a duplicate.  The so-called duplicate visa refusal question is the catch-all question, not for when the ECO makes a mistake

Answer (score 1):

The form asks for monthly income in the case of employment with another entity and annual income in the case of self-employment. You might have made a mistake by stating your annual income instead of your monthly income. You should check on your form. In this case, you should reapply, point out your error and your new application should be judged on its merits without prejudice. Just be more carefully filling the form.

If you did in fact state the correct income and the ECO had made an error on his/her refusal, you should email the UK's embassy in your country, the post that issued the refusal as well as UKVI's email service. They will sort it out.

Comment: I have added a scanned copy of my application which shows clearly my answer to the question of employment monthly income  = RM 4850.

Comment: BTW, My company director who answered the embassy call remembers that the officer asked if I receive 60K a month. He corrected them that its 5k a month. I am %100 they made an error. But have no faith they will entertain my complain.

Comment: @Azu Bain if they don't rectify their error you should send them a pre protocol action for a judicial review. If it gets to that stage they will be asked by the judge to pay for your legal costs as well. You don't want a unjustified refusal on your record and you don't want to let them get away with it. My friend was in a similar situation but the ECM overturned the ECO's refusal after a polite email.